# My image icon is not getting displayed in iphone x device ,when I try to change it to portrait view then is it visible

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular, typescript

And even after portrait view to normal view it is visible. It is not displaying in only first time load case, it shows blank ,I tried each and every css methods. But someone help. This issue comes only in iphone x device
U have shared the code
this is without icon picture in iphonex:

[image]

expected with icon image:

[image]

this is .ts code

```
 getStepIconSource(currentStep) {
if (this.journeyPlayedSteps && this.journeyPlayedSteps.length > 0) {
  let ind = this.journeyPlayedSteps.findIndex(ob => ob.step_id == currentStep.step_id);
  if (ind > -1) {
    if (this.journeyPlayedSteps[ind].status == 'Completed') {
      if (this.journeyPlayedSteps[ind].type == 'Game' && currentStep.is_key_learn_mandatory) {
        if (this.journeyPlayedSteps[ind].key_learn_attempted_date && this.journeyPlayedSteps[ind].key_learn_attempted_date > 0) {
          // return '../assets/images/icons/played.svg';
          return '../assets/images/icons/played.png';
        } else {
          return '../assets/images/icons/play.svg';
        }
      } else {
        // return '../assets/images/icons/played.svg';
        return '../assets/images/icons/played.png';
      }
```

Comment: Are you able to test it on Android device? Also, how do you handle icon display - in template or in ts? Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: Yes i am able to test it on android devices,it works well with android

Comment: Also share HTML & CSS Code Here

Comment: this is html code====>  <div class="dpFlex actionIcon" style="background-color: #FFF">
                                  <img src="{{getStepIconSource(stp)}}" id="stepIconTour" />
                                  <span>
                                    <hr style="width: 20px; margin: 10px 0 0 0;">
                                  </span>

Comment: .ts code I have mentioned above in the description

Comment: Are journeyPlayedSteps and/or currentStep/stp values taken from subscription? Maybe they're not present when the template loads, but become accessible milliseconds later? IF you log the steps/conditions inside the getStepIconSource method - what do you get?

Comment: Actually I am not able to log it because the issue only visible on actual device

Comment: Can you do alert instead of console.log?

Comment: yes I will do and check

Comment: alert is not displaying on iphone x first time load

Comment: Please someone help?